# What is the running time and space complexity of a arithmetic encode/decode algorithm?

Tags: math, encoding, time-complexity, space-complexity

I read the article written by cleary et all. But it doesn't explain the Complexity in the worse case. In some document on net, i read that complexity is O(n), but in another document it's O(N log n). Can someone help me? thanks

Comment: https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee398a/handouts/papers/WittenACM87ArithmCoding.pdf

Comment: Just from looking at your question, I can say that: If `n` in O(n) is the same as the `N` in the O(N log n) from that other article, then both statements are equivalent. Then that log(n) from the second article is just a constant in the statement from the first, and can be omitted.

Comment: yes, but what does it refers? One to explain the linear time, another logarithmic time.Maybe you should take a look at the article

Comment: Update: I think that the complexity in the article is O(n). in the next years, they've  improved the general algorithms to time complexity O(logN). Can you confirm me?

Comment: Just think about it. The basic algorithm encodes a character by modifying a range. The range modification is a constant-time operation. You do this for every input character, hence you have a time complexity of `O(n)` (with `n` being the number of input symbols). If you need to look up the subrange for a given symbol in a tree-like data structure, you get another factor of `log k` (with `k` being the number of potential symbols). The complexity can never drop below `O(n)` because the algorithm must obviously inspect every input symbol.

Comment: ok, i think i understand. So, if i have the probability distribution saved into tree data structure (range), then complexity is O(N log n). is it correct? Otherwise, if i use the fixed model saved into array structure is O(N).